# Why is linear gradient working well in simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, gradient

I am using the following code to generate a linear gradient for an iOs Button

```
private func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor])
{
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addToCart.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}

 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    gradientLayer.frame = self.addToCart.bounds
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.applyGradient(colors: [UIColor(red: 234, green: 67, blue: 53, alpha: 0.06).cgColor, 
    UIColor(red: 234, green: 67, blue: 53, alpha: 1).cgColor])   
  
}
```

The gradient is working fine on simulator but not or real device
Here is what I get on simulator

[image]

And here is what I get on real device

[image]

Which is totally different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RGB color channel values are not valid. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init) for `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha:)`. The RGBA values should be between 0 and 1. If you look on your console, you will likely see an error that says something like:

> [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.

You should divide your RGB values by 255:

```swift
applyGradient(colors: [
    UIColor(red: 234/255, green: 67/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 0.06).cgColor,
    UIColor(red: 234/255, green: 67/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
])
```

---

FYI, if you want to add a breakpoint on `UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents`, see “Pause on a Symbol Outside Your Code” in [Setting Breakpoints to Pause Your Running App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting_breakpoints_to_pause_your_running_app), e.g. add symbolic breakpoint:

[image]

And specify `UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents` symbol:

[image]

And the debugger will stop at the offending line:

[image]

Comment: HI rob I followed everything and It is not working If I use 234/255 I end up with no gradient even

Comment: Double check the background colors, the alpha values, etc. E.g. you probably have this on top of a red view, so going from this color to transparent means that you don't see any transition.

Comment: FWIW, the only way I could get your code to generate the images in your question, I had to set the background color to red. Once I fixed the gradient, I had to change the background color accordingly. (Note, once the color channels are back to values between 0 and 1, you'll have to change your colors to yield something akin to your desired look and feel.)

Comment: Thank you for the help